# typescript filter array on 2 parameters

Tags: arrays, typescript, filter

In order to filter an array on possibly 2 parameters I have written the following code:

```
filterStudies(searchString?: string) {
        if (searchString && !this.selectedModalityType) {
            this.studies = this.fullStudyList.filter(function (study) {
                return (study.Code.toUpperCase().includes(searchString.toUpperCase())) ||
                    (study.Description.toUpperCase().includes(searchString.toUpperCase()));
                })
        } else if (!searchString && this.selectedModalityType) {
            console.log(this.selectedModalityType)
            this.studies = this.fullStudyList.filter(function (study) {
                return (study.ModalityType.Code.toUpperCase() === this.selectedModalityType.toUpperCase())
            })
        } else if (searchString && this.selectedModalityType) {
            this.studies = this.fullStudyList.filter(function (study) {
                return (study.Code.toUpperCase().includes(searchString.toUpperCase())) ||
                    (study.Description.toUpperCase().includes(searchString.toUpperCase())) &&
                    (study.ModalityType.Code.toUpperCase() === this.selectedModalityType.toUpperCase())
            })
        }
    }
```

filterStudies(searchString?: string) is called when typing in a textbox that.

The other way of filtering could be by selecting a value from a dropdown box. Achieved by this code:

```
handleSelection(value:any){
            this.selectedModalityType = value;
            console.log(value)
            this.filterStudies()
        }
```

All works fine until this code is hit:

```
this.studies = this.fullStudyList.filter(function (study) {
                return (study.ModalityType.Code.toUpperCase() === this.selectedModalityType.toUpperCase())
            })
```

Error message : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedModalityType' of undefined, I see it is actually logged in the line before.

What am I missing??

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your funtcion, `this` is not the same this as the line before.

This will work:

```
let self = this;
this.studies = this.fullStudyList.filter(function (study) {
                return (study.ModalityType.Code.toUpperCase() === self.selectedModalityType.toUpperCase())
            })
```

You can read this to learn more: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript

> The this keyword in JavaScript (and thus TypeScript) behaves differently than it does in many other languages. This can be very surprising, especially for users of other languages that have certain intuitions about how this should work.
> (...)
> Typical symptoms of a lost this context include:
>
> - A class field (this.foo) is undefined when some other value was expected